# Partial derivative of bivariate cdf

Tags: bivariate, partial-effect

Suppose the bivariate cdf $F(a,b)=Pr(X\leq a, Y\leq b)$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$. Is it true that $\frac{\partial Pr(X\leq a, Y\leq b)}{\partial a}=Pr(X=a,Y\leq b)$?

Comment: Would you need to ask this question if the "$,Y\le b$" references were dropped?  If not, then consider how their appearance possibly could change the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes it clear.